# Using scikit-learn for mixed L1, L2 penalized regressions

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

Is there a nice way to include more general combinations of L1 and L2 penalties in `scikit-learn`? For example, input some of the parameters for L1 penalty and others for L2?

Comment: There's `elastic net`, which is basically a mixture of `l1` and `l2`. This can be useful if you want sparse solutions, but want to penalize the `explaining away` effect of correlated values. I guess a mixture of `L1` and `L2` on different components of the vector is hard to motivate. What are you trying to model with that?

Comment: A simple example is a linear model Y = A X + S where S is sparse shot noise (heavy outliers). You could probably crudely attack this by applying an L1 penalty to S. There are other ways of doing this of course. I think scikit learn Lasso might be limited to a coord-descent solver which I think requires a certain decomposition of the L1 term (separability) ... so more general L1 penalties will require a different treatment.

Comment: For me it's not obvious how you can convert this into a `Lasso` model. `Lasso` puts a prior on the weights `x`. If you dig a little into the statistics of linear regression you will see, that there's the bold assumption, that the residuals `y-Ax` are normally distributed. This does not seem to be the case here. Changing the `penalty` thus the prior on the weights is probably not the right way to tackle that problem.